# @Autowired doesn't work in Spring and Vaadin integration

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I'm trying to integrate `Spring` with `Vaadin`, but I can't use the `@Autowired` annotation in my Vaadin classes.

Firstly, I created the followed maven structure

[image]

This is my *web.xml*

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Vaadin Web Application</display-name>
<context-param>
<description>Vaadin production mode</description>
<param-name>productionMode</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextClass</param-name>
<param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
<listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.mycompany.config.AutowiringApplicationServlet</servlet-class>

<init-param>
<description>Vaadin UI to display</description>
<param-name>UI</param-name>
<param-value>com.mycompany.ui.MyUI</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Vaadin Application Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my *application-context.xml*

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/vaadin" />
<property name="username" value="postgres" />
<property name="password" value="tobbis" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myUnit"/>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.repository"></jpa:repositories>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />
```

Now I created my `UserService` that is within `com.mycompany.services` package

```
@Service
public class UserService {

public void saveUser(User user){

    System.out.println("Test to Save");

}
}
```

And finally, I have my Panel where I want to inject the service

```
public class UserPanel extends VerticalLayout {


@Autowired
UserService service;

public UserPanel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Injector.inject(this);

    service.saveUser();
}

}
```

but the result is always the same

```
 Error creating bean with name 'com.mycompany.ui.UserPanel': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Could not autowire field: com.mycompany.services.UserService com.mycompany.ui.UserPanel.service; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
 No matching bean of type [com.aiem.services.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
 Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: IIRC, the "GUI" classes of GWT get translated into Javascript for execution in the browser. So, there is no way you can add spring support to GUI classes (you could add it to backend/server classes).

Comment: It has been a long time since I have used GWT, though.

Comment: @SJuan76 UserPanel is extending VericalLayout so it's not translated to javascript, it's server side code.

Comment: Just to make you aware, I am sure that you know cannot inject classes which are not managed by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your *UserService* at applicationContext.xml

```
<bean name="userService" class="com.mycompany.services.UserService"></bean>
```

Comment: It's annotated with @Service so that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @user2069976 see my other answer: I don't think it's a problem with `UserService`, but with `UserPanel`: it's not created by the Spring bean factory.

Comment: Looks like something wrong with imports, package at Exception is not the same as target class package.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,

```
Injector.inject(this);
```

is not something from Spring, you may be mixing it with another framework.

Instead, I would make `UserPanel` a prototype-scoped Spring component (meaning it can be instantiated and autowired by Spring, but you remain responsible for it's lifecycle).

```
@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class UserPanel extends VerticalLayout {
```

Note that a new instance will be created anytime `UserPanel` is retrieved from the context (e.g. autowired in another object).  It could be best to control the creation of instances yourself by explicitly invoking

```
context.getBean(UserPanel.class)
```

at the right time.

Comment: if I put Component and Scope annotations on the UserPanel,then when try to do context.getBean(UserPanel.class) i get this error: No unique bean of type [com.aiem.ui.UserPanel] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:

Comment: @user2069976 You have `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />` but your `UserPanel` class is in `com.aiem.ui`.  Or did you change the xml before posting your question?

Comment: btw Spring should log the beans it creates so you can check your logging as well.

Comment: i changed it before posting the question, the paths seems ok, i don't know

Answer (score 0):

`AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` is not meant to be used with XML config. It is supposed to be used with the `@Configuration` annotated classes.

Since you're using an xml file for Spring config, then you should instead *remove* these lines from web.xml:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextClass</param-name>
<param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And then by default Spring will use the `XmlWebApplicationContext` and pick up your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same scenario than you. At the end, the solution is at the [Vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring+Integration).

Seems that the problem is that we are using Vaadin context and not Spring context, and therefore we need to do the trick showed in the documentation (SpringHelper) to obtain any bean. Outside of the Spring context, the autowiring is not goint to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon for enabling autowiring via annotations: http://vaadin.xpoft.ru/.
Here is the link to the Vaadin site: http://vaadin.com/addon/springvaadinintegration. Hope it helps.